# The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in move_uploaded_file

Tags: php, file-upload

Im studying how to upload PDF with php and Im having a problem that Im not able to find what I have wrong.

I have an input type = "file" like this:

```
<label class="line">
            <span> Choose a PDF: </span>
            <input type="file"  name="pdf" size="60" />
 </label>
```

And then I have the code below, to create a directory to store pdfs, if the directory didnt exist yet.

```
if(!empty($_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'])){

        $folder = '../uploads/pdfs';
        $year   = date('Y');
        $month  = date('m');

        if(!file_exists($folder.$year)){
           mkdir($folder.$month,0755);

        }
        if(!file_exists($folder.$year.'/'.$month)){
            mkdir($folder.$year.'/'.$month,0755);
        }

         $mypdf = $_FILES['pdf'];
        $ext = substr($img['name'],-3);
        $f['pdf'] = $year.'/'.$month.'/'.$f['url'].'.'.$ext;
        move_uploaded_file($mypdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/');

    }
```

The mkdir to create the directory is working fine but the pdf its not uploading.

**And Im getting this errors:**

**Warning: move_uploaded_file():** The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in move_uploaded_file($mypdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/');

**Warning: move_uploaded_file():** Unable to move 'F:\Xampp\tmp\php1BD6.tmp' to '../uploads/pdfs2014/04/' in move_uploaded_file($mypdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a filename to the move_uploaded_files function as well, so it knows where to save the file(directory) and under what filename.

```
move_uploaded_file($mypdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'."my_newly_uploaded_file.pdf");
```

or if you want to keep the original filename

```
move_uploaded_file($mypdf['tmp_name'], $folder.$year.'/'.$month.'/'.$mypdf["name"]);
```

Comment: Ah ok..I get it, I need the directory but also the filename at the end! I didnt understood that! Thank you very much!

Comment: Exactly. Please take the time to close the question if it was the correct solution to your issue. :)